# Selecting implementation class for the interface

Tags: java, interface

I have 4 different algorithms for data processing and I want to define an interface for accessing them. The only difficulty I am facing is that is it possible to specify the implementation classname when calling a method from interface. If yes, how? Idea should be sufficient

```
Map<Integer, Float> getResults(Algorithm.classname, Integer id);
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @UnholySheep as I said, I want to define a single interface and call different implementation classes.

Comment: I'd make an enum with all algorithms names and a factory which returns a concrete instance by an enum value